# Infinite Scroll jQuery & Laravel 5 Paginate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, infinite-scroll

I am successfully returning the data from Controller

```
public function index()
 {
    $posts = Post::with('status' == 'verified)
                      ->paginate(30);

    return view ('show')->with(compact('posts'));
 }
```

Also, I am successfully showing everything in my view:

```
 <div id="content" class="col-md-10">
    @foreach (array_chunk($posts->all(), 3) as $row)
        <div class="post row">
            @foreach($row as $post)
                <div class="item col-md-4">
                    <!-- SHOW POST -->
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach
    {!! $posts->render() !!}
 </div>
```

Everything is working nicely until now.

However, I didn't get the official documentation at all. What is '`div.navigation`' and '`#content div.post`'? What should they be in my case?

> *Snippet From Documentation:*
>
> ```
> $('#content').infinitescroll({
>
>    navSelector  : "div.navigation",            
>                    // selector for the paged navigation (it will be ?>hidden)
>     nextSelector : "div.navigation a:first",    
>                    // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
>     itemSelector : "#content div.post"          
>                    // selector for all items you'll retrieve
> });
> ```

**Edit: My Javascript So Far**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
(function() {
     var loading_options = {
        finishedMsg: "<div class='end-msg'>Congratulations! You've reached the end of the internet</div>",
        msgText: "<div class='center'>Loading news items...</div>",
        img: "/assets/img/ajax-loader.gif"
     };

     $('#content').infinitescroll({
         loading: loading_options,
         navSelector: "ul.pagination",
         nextSelector: "ul.navigation a:first",
         itemSelector: "#content div.item"
     });
 });
});
```

The [<[1]2]3]>] part is created at the bottom of the page but infinite scroll doesn't work. Also, I get no logs or errors in the console.

Comment: Well, it's described in the comments what those selector are. `div.navigation` is your navigation (which you don't have, but you could output it like `$posts->render()`). and `itemSelector` is the selector for one item (in your case: `div.col-md-4`. Think about adding another class like `post` to it).

Comment: I edited my question and added classes as you told, however, I still couldn't connect them in my brain. Can you please show me?

Comment: See my infinit scroll plug in for L5 pagination here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31853472/laravel-infinite-scroll-for-pagination-output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to add the pagination itself like this after the closing `#content` div:

```
{!! $posts->render() !!}
```

This will output something like:

```
<ul class="pagination"><li><a>...</a></li>
```

To overwrite the pagination presenter have a look at [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28542607/261713).

Then your configuration looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loading_options = {
        finishedMsg: "<div class='end-msg'>Congratulations! You've reached the end of the internet</div>",
        msgText: "<div class='center'>Loading news items...</div>",
        img: "/assets/img/ajax-loader.gif"
    };

    $('#content').infinitescroll({
        loading: loading_options,
        navSelector: "ul.pagination",
        nextSelector: "ul.pagination a:first",
        itemSelector: "#content div.item"
    });
});
```

Basically, the infinite scroller will call the pagination links for you and thus needs to know, where everything is located to put it all together.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have one last question. Where should I put `class="pagination"`? Which one should I change? Does it explicitly has to be `ul`?

Comment: You put `{!! $posts->render() !!}` at the end of your `#content` div. You don't have to put `class="pagination"` anywhere as this gets output by the Laravel function. And yes, it has to be `ul` because that is the format used by the `render` function.

Comment: I got very confused. I understand that I will only put `{!! $posts->render() !!}` to output `<ul class="pagination">...` bit. So inside `class="item"`, is that right? And then under that, I will add `</ul>`

Comment: Sorry for being confusing. Don't put it inside your foreach loop but outside (also see my edited answer).

Comment: I followed the guide you showed, but couldn't make it work. I edited the question and added my javascript code. Can you please take a look? Thanks so much in advance

Comment: Not really, I added the js code in the question, but it doesnt work :/

Comment: I tried to expand my answer, please take a look. But without further information (like console logs, how you implemented infinitescroll etc.) it's hard to tell where the problem could be. Also try to move {!! $posts->render() !!} outside of the #content div. Looking at the documentation that could be your problem.

Comment: +1 for both and thanks for your help! For me it worked adding `{!! $posts->appends($filters)->render()!!}` instead of `{!! $posts->render() !!}` in blade and `nextSelector : "ul.pagination li:last-child a",` instead of  `nextSelector: "ul.navigation a:first",` in JS infinite scroll options.